# Can't infer proper type myself in Kotlin when using JavaFX

Tags: javafx, kotlin

I just started to study Kotlin and JavaFX by following tutorial.
I could see blank JavaFX windows, and I proceed next step that using FXML.

```
import javafx.application.Application
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader
import javafx.scene.Scene
import javafx.stage.Stage

class AppMain : Application() {

    override fun start(primaryStage: Stage) {
        primaryStage.title = "Try JavaFX"
        val fxml = javaClass.getResource("fxml/Main.fxml")
        val root = FXMLLoader.load(fxml) // ERRORS here! `load`
        val scene = Scene(root)

        primaryStage.scene = scene

        primaryStage.show()
    }

}
```

However, I couldn't figure out that how to avoid the type inferencing error like:
`Error:(12, 31) Kotlin: Type inference failed: Not enough information to infer parameter T in fun <T : Any!> load(p0: URL!): T! Please specify it explicitly.`

From the message, I understand that I have to write the type of variable `fxml` explicitly.
But I have no idea that what type should be labeled to `fxml`.

I tried to read the document about JavaFX, but I couldn't figure it out.(I'm not familiar with Java and Kotlin)
I tried to type like `URL` but it does not make sense.

Many JavaFX & Kotlin example codes that I could find from google does not seems to have the problem like this. (Are the example codes written in previous version?)
What type should I put for the variable?
Or did I miss something other?

### Environment and Codes

#### Environment

- JDK 11
- JavaFX 11
- Kotlin 1.2.71

#### My complete trial code

https://github.com/QuietJoon/StudyKotlin-JavaFX/tree/fxml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem isn't the parameter to the `FXMLLoader.load` function (which is a `java.net.URL` object, as returned by `javaClass.getResource`). It's that this function **returns** a generic type:

`public static <T> T load(URL location)`

The Kotlin compiler needs to know what type your `root` variable will be (as you've not explicitly defined it), but it can't know that as there's nothing in the code that will allow it to infer this.

A quick Google returned [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/get_started/FXMLExample.java.html) example which has this code in it (in Java):

`Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("fxml_example.fxml"));`

As you can see here, the `root` variable is of type `Parent`.  So what you need to do is provide this type (i.e. what you expect the `load` function to return) in some way.  Here are two different ways you could do this:

1. Specify the type explicitly when declaring the variable: `val root: Parent = FXMLLoader.load(fxml)`
2. Specify the generic type when calling the method: `val root = FXMLLoader.load<Parent>(fxml)`

Note also that in your `build.gradle` file in your github repo there's a mistake that means the code didn't immediately compile when I fetched it:

`compile "org.openjfx.javafx.fxml:11:$platform"` should be `compile "org.openjfx:javafx-fxml:11:$platform"` (one of the dots should be a colon).

Comment: Thanks too much, Gibbs! and sorry for my late reaction.